# Assign dynamic ids to hidden fields when iterating over a collection

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to assign dynamic ids to `h:inputHidden` components?

**EDIT1**

I am trying to assign the ids inside a `ui:repeat` tag when iterating over a collection of elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to set the ID based on the iteration value of an `<ui:repeat>`. But you don't need it anyway. They will by default already get dynamic and unique IDs based on the iteration index.

E.g.

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
        <h:inputHidden id="hidden" value="#{item.value}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

will generate this HTML during view render time

```html
<form id="form" name="form">
    <input type="hidden" id="form:0:hidden" name="form:0:hidden" value="item1value" />
    <input type="hidden" id="form:1:hidden" name="form:1:hidden" value="item2value" />
    <input type="hidden" id="form:2:hidden" name="form:2:hidden" value="item3value" />
</form>
```

If you want to manually control the ID, you'd need to use `<c:forEach>` instead, because `<ui:repeat>` doesn't generate multiple JSF components, but lets its children (which is a single `<h:inputHidden>` in the above example) generate HTML multiple times. The `<c:forEach>` will generate multiple JSF components which then each generate HTML only once (so you effectively end up with multiple `<h:inputHidden>` components in JSF component tree).

E.g.

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.list}" var="item">
        <h:inputHidden id="#{item.id}" value="#{item.value}" />
    </c:forEach>
</h:form>
```

which will basically generate this JSF component tree during view build time

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputHidden id="item1id" value="#{bean.list[0].value}" />
    <h:inputHidden id="item2id" value="#{bean.list[1].value}" />
    <h:inputHidden id="item3id" value="#{bean.list[2].value}" />
</h:form>
```

which in turn will generate this HTML during view render time

```html
<form id="form" name="form">
    <input type="hidden" id="form:item1id" name="form:item1id" value="item1value" />
    <input type="hidden" id="form:item2id" name="form:item2id" value="item2value" />
    <input type="hidden" id="form:item3id" name="form:item3id" value="item3value" />
</form>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Thank you for responding. You are a legend in the world of JSF. I get an NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: 
 org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages over the namespace declaration for c:forEach. I am using xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" as namespace.

Comment: For JSF2 you need `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"` instead, with the `/jsp` in the URI.

Comment: I think you meant `<h:inputHidden id="#{item.id}" value="#{item.value}" />` for the `ui:repeat` example.

Comment: No I did absolutely not mean that. It's not possible to set the ID by `<ui:repeat>` that way.

Comment: I get an exception: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus

Comment: Your environment doesn't have JSTL installed. Apparently you're using a barebones servletcontainer like Tomcat or Jetty instead of a fullfledged appserver like Glassfish or JBoss AS. You'd need to install JSTL separately (like you did for JSF). Head to our `[jstl]` tag wiki page for download links and instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info Pick the JSTL 1.2 one.

Comment: Did that, it's working. Thank you. I have another JSF question posted that is related to a datatable submit.

Answer (score 1):

They get assigned a dynamic ID by default. You can also specify `id="#{..}` to customize it.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I was searching a way to create multiple hidden input fields with ui:repeat over a collection and found that EL values are not supported for ids. So I thought that is applies all situations.

Comment: I guess you can have an iteration variable and use it in the ID

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add any random number also (`id="#{}"`),but

add ***functionally related ids to hidden components***, that will be helpful

for example if it is employee form ,you may add empid to it.